# PHP permissions

Tags: php

**Can someone please explain best practice for permissions with PHP.**
What case should something be writable, executable, what owner is best, etc. ?

Using an apache server

Moved to [What should the Unix file system permissions be for PHP files under Apache?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16032/php-permissions)