# Do PHP-FPM (and other PHP handlers) need execute permissions on the PHP files they're serving?

Tags: php, apache, nginx

I read in [a post at Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/471242/nginx-user-group-config/471268#471268) that PHP-FPM needs **execute** permissions. However, the answer in [When creating a website, what permissions and directory structure?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13658/when-creating-a-website-what-permissions-and-directory-structure/13661#13661) only grants **read** and **write** permissions to PHP-FPM. Maybe I don't quite understand how PHP handlers (or CGI in general) work, but the two claims seem contradictory to me.

As I understand, when Apache / Nginx gets a request for `foobar.php`, it "passes" the file to an appropriate handler. That is, I imagine it's as if `www-root` (or `apache` or whomever the webserver's running as) were to run some command,

```
/usr/sbin/php-fpm foobar.php
```

Actually, no, that's naive, I just realized. PHP-FPM must be a running instance (if it's to be performant, and cache, etc.), so probably PHP-FPM is just being *told*, "Hey, quick, process this file for me!"

In either case, I don't see why **execute** permissions are necessary. It's not like the webserver needs to literally *execute* the file, *i.e.*

```
./foobar.php
```

Is the Server Fault answer simply mistaken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `php-fpm` user does NOT need `execute` permissions on PHP files. It only needs read permission, as PHP files are **parsed** by PHP preprocessor and **not executed** directly.

Comment: Thanks! I take it however that some (if not all) CGI programs must be executable, _e.g._ Python scripts? Or is _everything_ handled by such a "handler" that only needs read access.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct - the file does not need to be 755 executable. The file being passed to PHP-FPM should have permissions set to 644 (owner read/write, group read, global read). This is especially needed on shared hosting so that others can not overwrite your files.